# The scrollview in the xamarin.forms shell will automaticlly margin to top?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I find that with xamarin.forms shell. the scrollview will automatically margin to the top,and I cannot change it.Is there any way to change it?

I have tried many solutions and searched ,but there is no one can solve it .
It seems that It will auto margin for the titlebar(actionbar).I've already hide the navigation bar.

No matter Specify the Height or the x,y position it is not work.

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
          <ScrollView>
             <Image Source="a.png" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
          </ScrollView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3FSi.png)

I want to Make the Image up to the top and do not leave white space.

Answer (score 1):

The part where you have the white space is called the `Safe Area`

By default, Xamarin Forms does not use the safe area.

But if you want to use it any way it can be done something like this:

```
On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOS>().SetUseSafeArea(true);
```

Also, add the following using Statement `using Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;`

The same can be done via XAML something like this on your `ContentPage`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" 
ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true" >
```

For a detailed understanding of how this works, you can check this [blog by Xamarin](https://blog.xamarin.com/making-ios-11-even-easier-xamarin-forms/)

Comment: Thank you. why haven't I thought of this .your answer is useful.

Comment: I tried it not work,even if I specified the scoreview height=WindowHeight.

Comment: What version of XF are you using ?

Comment: Visual studio for mac 8.0 build 2972

Comment: Xamarin Forms not Visual studio!!

Comment: xf .ios 12.2.1.16

Comment: Check the NuGet package for Xamarin Forms not this

Comment: xf version is:3.6.0.264807.It is not worked but I'v found the Margin in the blog you give and give a margin of -44(depend on the safe area),it worked.

Comment: I see shall i add that as an answer?

Comment: If you found that in the blog then this is the only way!

Comment: no no no ,I mean the code in the blog is not work .so I think of a solution for the being time. It is not the only way. It is my personal thought.